Stein and Shakarchi Complex Analysis Chapter 8, Proof of Lemma 1.3
I am confused about the proof to Lemma 1.3 in Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis Chapter 8 (Conformal Mappings).
Here is a screenshot of the Lemma and its proof:

My question is is the following: if $u: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, why are we allowed to use $u$ as the real part of the holomorphic function $G$? $u$ can take on complex values, but the real part of $G$ is by definition real, so what does it mean that the real part of $G$ is $u$, which can be nonreal?

There is a typo, the codomain of $u$ should be $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{C}$.

The co-domain of $u: U\to \mathbb C$ was written with the understanding that the composition makes sense, i.e. that $u$ is real-valued. It is important to keep in mind that stating a co-domain is not the same as stating the image of the function itself, i.e. in this case we do not have that $u(U)= \mathbb C$.
